# Optimize or minimize a vector function in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, vector, minimize

I need to minimize a vector function at all points of x f(x) = a+b*x+c*x^2+d*x^3. The values of a,b,c,d has to be optimized for the same. Is their any algorithm in matlab that can do the same? I used gamultiobj algorithm for the same, but it generated a large number of these values for each pareto point. I just need a single set of value for the same.

Comment: what does it mean to "optimize for the same"? the same what?

Comment: I have certain value of a,b,c,d (known values), that generates f(x). However, I need a set of  a,b,c,d , such that I obtain a f(x) value that is minimum at all x. This minimized function is not known to us.  I tried using gamultiobj (Multiple objective optimization), but not clear of its working, as it generates a large number of different a,b,c,d values.

Comment: I suspect you need more constraints - Whatever values of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` you pick, you can always find a different combination that will yield an even lower value of `f(x)`, for example by reducing `d`.

Comment: Well, you can always set `a` to -Inf :). I can guarantee you this will give `f(x)` the value of -Inf for x < Inf. For x == Inf it will be undefined I guess. Anyway, even though it is a solution I do _not_ say it is a _good_ solution. My point is that optimizing needs to be done in terms of properly defined constraints, otherwise you will just get rubbish I am afraid.

Comment: Yes even I define a contstrant in x, and the variable parameters, will I be able to  minimize the function in matlab at all points ?